# Keep duplicates in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I want to have an array of key:value pairs, but there might be duplicates.

Intention: Array of tasks, and each task has multiple operations. (I need the key/value for the operations, only that is required)

Right now the last item's value keeps overwriting the first key.

I currently have this, which solves my issue, but is there a better way to do this?

```
[
    [
          {
            resize: [1200, 1200]
          }, {
            moveTo: "dest/nick"
          }, {
            rename: "{base}-12.{ext}"
          }, {
            toWeb: true
          }, {
            rename: "{base}.{ext}"
          }
        ], [
          {
            resize: [1000, 1000]
          }, {
            rename: "{base}-10.{ext}"
          }
        ]
      ]
```

The `resize`, `moveTo` and `rename` are only pseudo options, many more things. And I need duplicates.

**edit**

This is a configuration. (Input) kinda like json, I think. It has to be parsed

**EDIT**

**The above code works** I simply wanted a better way to do this, so I have asked it over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105161/a-better-way-to-structure-json-array-with-objects)

Comment: Is the array filled dynamically? That is, are the tasks added dynamically?

Comment: You've just posted an object, which tells us nothing about the problem. If you're just appending to an array with `array.push`, there should be no reason that your tasks are being overwritten. Perhaps you're using some form of `array[key] = ...`?

Comment: @Mattias defined in a config file

Comment: show us some input data and your function that proceeds the input data.

Comment: @JoshuaK that is the input object

Comment: Well the issue has to be what is reading it...

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it is easier to think from reverse side, first how you would use it, then how you should define the data structure.

e.g. `task[i].operation1; task[i].operation2`

then it should be:

```
task = [
  { resize: [1200, 1200], moveTo: "dest/nick, ..... }, 
  { resize: [1000, 1000], rename: "{base}-10.{ext}", ..... }
]
```

Comment: When I do this, if I have resize again it will overwrite the first resize, since it will be a duplicate key. And I need both, because I need to resize then resize the result if needed.

Comment: it will be easier if you can post the corresponding code block where you see the "duplicate key". I think you confuse yourself on iterating the array instead.

Comment: I changed the example

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Is there any reason why you would need to resize or rename more than one time? In the exemple, I think it shows a case in which the first occurence of the dupplicate is more than useless.

Comment: @Frederik.L it was the fastest sample I can give (copy paste) I am mobile. There are multiple different operations. There is an option that when repeated it gives a different result.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Then you should have an array for each operation : `{ something: [ [200,100], [10, 15], ... ] }, ...` and for running it, you could have something like : `for (opList in tasks[current]) for (op in opList) op.run()`.